# How to draw on the screenshot captured

Tags: c#, screenshot, screen-capture

I have captured current window using C# code, the code is shown below. I want to draw a rectangle on the captured section(For highlighting things). Anyone know how can I highlight the things using C# code? I want to draw on the cursor position below mentioned.

```
 public Bitmap CaptureScreen()
        {
            enmScreenCaptureMode screenCaptureMode = enmScreenCaptureMode.Window;
            Rectangle bounds;

            if (screenCaptureMode == enmScreenCaptureMode.Screen)
            {
                bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);
                CursorPosition = Cursor.Position;
            }
            else
            {
                var foregroundWindowsHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
                var rect = new Rect();
                GetWindowRect(foregroundWindowsHandle, ref rect);
                bounds = new Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right - rect.Left, rect.Bottom - rect.Top);
                CursorPosition = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - rect.Left, Cursor.Position.Y - rect.Top);

            }

            var result = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);


            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
            {
                Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red);
                g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);

            }

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: The way the question is asked, I'd consider it as too broad. Please elaborate on what you've tried and where you're stuck,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have passed the clicked point and element clicked using the AutomationElement, and drawn an eclipse using the elements BoundingRectangle property. Code shown below.

```
 public Bitmap CaptureScreen(System.Windows.Point point, AutomationElement element)
        {
            enmScreenCaptureMode screenCaptureMode = enmScreenCaptureMode.Window;
            Rectangle bounds;

            var foregroundWindowsHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
            var rect = new Rect();
            GetWindowRect(foregroundWindowsHandle, ref rect);
            if (screenCaptureMode == enmScreenCaptureMode.Screen)
            {
                bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);
                CursorPosition = Cursor.Position;
            }
            else
            {

                bounds = new Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right - rect.Left, rect.Bottom - rect.Top);
                CursorPosition = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - rect.Left, Cursor.Position.Y - rect.Top);
            }

            var result = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
            {

                 Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red,2);
                g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
                //float drawX = (float)point.X - rect.Left;
                //float drawY = (float)point.Y - rect.Top;
                float drawX = (float)element.Current.BoundingRectangle.X - rect.Left;
                float drawY = (float)element.Current.BoundingRectangle.Y - rect.Top;
                g.DrawEllipse(pen, drawX, drawY, (float) element.Current.BoundingRectangle.Width, (float)element.Current.BoundingRectangle.Height);           
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to draw programmatically, maybe try [System.Drawing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.drawing.aspx).

You probably won't need the first line.

```
// Load the image (probably from your stream)
Image image = Image.FromFile( imagePath );

using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
{
    // Modify the image using g here... 
    // Create a brush with an alpha value and use the g.FillRectangle function
    SolidBrush shadowBrush = new SolidBrush(Red);
    g.DrawRectangle(shadowBrush, /*RectanglePointsHere*/);
}

image.Save( imageNewPath );
```

Comment: Thank you. I am trying with that.

Comment: You sould _always_ dispose resources like your [`SolidBrush`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.solidbrush) by putting it inside a `using` block.

Comment: Before saving the screenshot can I draw? Any way to draw from the above code?

Comment: Yes. It looks like your method returns an image, so just `using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(CaptureWindow(/*whatever your handle is*/))` as the second line and don't use the first line.